# Sibiling value calculate

Tags: jquery, siblings

**what else in this code**

```js
   var b1 = 2;
    $(".column-1").each(function(i, val) {
      if ($(this).text() == "2019") {
        $(this).siblings('.column-3').each(function(){
         if($(this).text() !==''){
           var r +=parseInt($(this).text());
           alert(r);
          }
        
      });
      }
      });
```

how to fix this error in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var b1 = 0;
$(".column-1").each(function(i, val) {
  if ($(this).text() == "2019") {
    var r=0;
    $(this).siblings('.column-3').each(function() {
               if($(this).text() !==''){
           r +=parseInt($(this).text());
           alert(r);
          }
    });
  }
  });
```

i solved this error